# Send data to another workbook via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I've made this little macro to get the name of file from a folder, split it to get information from it and store them in variables that I send to another Excel file...
And that's the part I'm struggling with ... I was abble to make it works the last friday but forget to save and I don't have backup. (Beginners issues) so I'm pretty sure I'm close to make it works again but I'm not finding why it doesn't work....

Can someone helps me pls ...

```
     
    Dim Chemin As String, Fichier As String, timeStamp As String
    Dim WB As Workbooks
    
    'Variable qui définit le fichier dans lequel le rapport est fait.
    'Set WB = Workbooks("EXCEL PATH WHERE I WRITE")
    
    'Définit le répertoire contenant les fichiers
    Chemin = "PATH WHERE THE FILES ARE STORE"
    
    'Variable qui récupère le nom des fichier peut importe l'extension.
    Fichier = Dir(Chemin & "*.*")
    
    'variable qui récupère le timestamp
    timeStamp = Split(Fichier, "_")(2)
    timeStamp = Split(timeStamp, ".")(0)

    'Boucle qui parse le nom de tous les fichiers
    Do While Len(Fichier) > 0
        'Variable pour aller à la derniere cellule de la la colonne
        emptyRowB  = Sheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        
        'Remplissage des données
        Workbooks("MyRapportFile.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(emptyRowB, 2).Value = timeStamp
        
        
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Sheet`? This is not defined. This `Sheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` should throw an error (Make sure you use `Option Explicit`). What does *"doesn't work"* mean exactly? Which errors do you get and where?

Comment: `Dim WB As Workbooks` should probably be `Dim WB As Workbook` if you want to set this variable a `Workbook`.

Comment: ```emptyRowB = Sheets("HP").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1``` 
i've also added Option explicit 
and what does not work is the adding data to the second workbook 
the error is Variable is not defined at line ```emptyrowB```
bellow you will find the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for VBA it is not clear in which workbook `emptyRowB = Sheets("HP")…` is unless you specify it like you did in `Workbooks("HP_Control-Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("HP")`.

Since you set your variable `wb` as that workbook

```
Set wb = Workbooks("HP_Control-Copy.xlsm")
```

you can use that

```
Dim emptyRowB As Long
emptyRowB = wb.Worksheets("HP").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

as well as here

```
wb.Worksheets("HP").Cells(emptyRowB, 2).Value = TimeStamp
```

---

In general you shoud never write `Range` or `Cells` without specifying in which worksheet and workbook that object is meant to be. Otherwise VBA assumes something because it cannot know for sure and it might assume something else than you and pick the wrong one. Don't let Excel guess!

Comment: Thnaks you for the answer, I still get an error, at ```emptyRowB = wb.Worksheets("HP").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1``` it tells me variable  ```emptyRowB ```is not defined.

Comment: @Melvinceylan Then define it: `Dim emptyRowB As Long`. Everey variable should be defined before its first use.

Comment: Thanks youu!! now i have another issues, It doesn't parse my folder where my files are stored, like it take only the first files in the  folder and never ends the loop

Comment: @Melvinceylan because you need a `Dir()` right before `Loop` to move to the next file.

Comment: i've added  ```dir ```dir (fichier) ``` and still doesn't work ... sorry i'm new to vba as well

Comment: just `Fichier = Dir()` you need to set your variable `Fichier` to be the next file.

Comment: Thanks  youuu! thanks for you time thanks for all xD have a great day !!

Comment: I've another question, Instead  having a variable for the path, i want to read all the file from  the folder where the macro file is.
ex: if my Macro file is in c:\ i want my macro to get the file name from c:\ and if i change its place to d:\ it get the  file name from d:\. 
is it possible ?

Comment: @Melvinceylan Check out `ThisWorkbook.Path`